# Repeat last command in Ipython console using spyder

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I am using the Spyder IDE for Python.

How can I repeat the last command in the IPython console?

I tried the up arrow - but it doesn't work.

any idea?

thanks.

Comment: The up arrow does seem to work. Are you in the right console? To view the Ipython console Go to `View -> Panes -> Ipython console`. The up arrow does work for me on my Mac. What version are you using and on what OS?

Comment: You have to have the IPython console focused for that to work. You can tell if that's the case by writing some text and seeing it printed in the console and not on the Editor or somewhere else.

Comment: did you solve it? I face the same problem. Using Spyder 3.0.2 on OSX 10.11.6